# Show daily rep totals on mobile site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

I think it would be nice if the reputation page on the mobile site showed the daily totals like the full site does.  This could fit in the existing date bar:

[image]

Comment: Offered a bounty to this. I think it wouldn't be very difficult to do and will offer a good improvement for the mobile site.